# How to create binary search tree from strings?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I have the following task: create a binary search tree from strings, and after that print them in alphabetical order.
As example,

```
orange
melon
apple
grapes
plum
banana
```

should have

```
apple
banana
grapes
melon
orange
plum
```

as output. I wrote a solution, but I have a problem: only the last string in input is printed (in this example, it's `banana`), and I can't find the mistake in my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct Node {
    char *data;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
} Node;
Node* getFreeNode(char *value) {
    Node* tmp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    tmp->left = tmp->right = NULL;
    tmp->data = value;
    return tmp;
}
void insert(Node **head, char *value) {
    Node* tmp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    tmp = *head;
    if (*head  == NULL) {
        *head = getFreeNode(value);
        return;
    }
    else{
        if (strcmp(value, tmp->data) > 0) {
            return insert(&(tmp->right), value);
        }
        else if (strcmp(value, tmp->data) < 0) {
            return insert(&(tmp->left), value);
        }
    }
}
void print_tree(Node *t)
{
    if (!t) return;
    print_tree(t->left);
    printf("%s\n", t->data);
    print_tree(t->right);
}
int main(){
    Node* a = NULL;
    FILE *in = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    char word[20];
    while (fscanf(in, "%s", word) == 1){
        insert(&a, word);
    }
    print_tree(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Node* tmp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node)); tmp = *head;` - You just leaked memory only one line after it was allocated. This isn't Java or C#. Don't allocate until you're *at* the position in the tree where the node is to be hung.

Comment: Note: You are mixing two methods, here. If you use a pointer to pointer, you don't need the return value. (neither the recursion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main`, your code is inserting `word`, which is a local stack variable. Hence, the `data` member of every node is pointing to the same address.   After you insert the memory address of `word` into the tree, you overwrite `word` with the next line of your file.  Again, the end effect is that the`data` member of ever node is pointing to the same string - the last string read in.

You need to make a copy of the string before inserting it into the tree.  Modify your getFreeNode function as follows:

```
Node* getFreeNode(char *value) {
    Node* tmp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    tmp->left = tmp->right = NULL;
    // tmp->data = value;
    tmp->data = strdup(value); // make a copy of the string for the new node
    return tmp;
}
```

[strdup](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) makes a copy of the string. You can use it by including `#include <strings.h>` at the top of your source file. Otherwise, it's identical to this:

```
tmp->data = malloc(strlen(value) + 1);
strcpy(tmp->data, value);
```

As the comments section in the original question suggests, this might not be your only bug.

Comment: Worth noting, the path-to-failure in the original code all started when the `value` arguments to `getFreeNode` and `insert` were *not* declared as `const char*`. Doing so would have checked one's self to ensure a copy was made when storing into the newly allocated node.